# How can CSR polling be restarted when joining a Corda Network?

Tags: corda

When joining the UAT Corda Network and running initial registration as required the Corda node was shutdown before the CSR completed. https://uat.network.r3.com/pages/joining/joining.html

The CSR has been approved by the Corda node does not have the correct certificates yet. When trying to start the node it throws an exception for missing certificates.

```
[ERROR] 2019-07-26T16:47:51,099Z [main] internal.NodeStartupLogging.invoke - Exception during node startup: One or more keyStores (identity or TLS) or trustStore not found.
Please either copy your existing keys and certificates from another node, or if you don't have one yet, fill out the config file and run corda.jar initial-registration.
Read more at: https://docs.corda.net/permissioning.html [errorCode=16fn52g, moreInformationAt=https://errors.corda.net/ENT/4.1/16fn52g] {}
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: One or more keyStores (identity or TLS) or trustStore not found. Please either copy your existing keys and certificates from another node, or if you don't have one yet, fill out the config file and run corda.jar initial-registration.
Read more at: https://docs.corda.net/permissioning.html
```

How can the CSR polling be completed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Initial registration can be rerun and will resume polling based on the CSR id that is located in the certificates directory as `certificate-request-id.txt`. Rerun the same command used to start the CSR.

`java -jar <CORDA JAR FILE> –initial-registration –network-root-truststore-password <TRUST STORE PASSWORD>`